# File is not getting deleted from sharepoint library

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Below is the code snippet, I am pretty much new to sharepoint

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(spSiteGUID))
 {
      using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(spWebGUID))
      {
          SPList list = web.Lists["Folder Name"];
          string sQuery = "<Where><BeginsWith><FieldRef Name='NameOrTitle'/><Value Type='Text'>" + fileName + "</Value></BeginsWith></Where>";
          var oQuery = new SPQuery();
          oQuery.Query = sQuery;
          oQuery.ViewAttributes = @"Scope='Recursive'";
          SPListItemCollection collListItems = list.GetItems(oQuery);

          foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
          {
              //file.UndoCheckOut();
              //file.CheckOut();
              oListItem.File.UndoCheckOut();
              oListItem.File.CheckOut();

              oListItem.Delete();                 

          }
      }
```

Intended file to be deleted is getting identified. Everything is working fine until last line which is oListItem.Delete(); . oListItem contains correct file name but for some reason delete is not happening. I don't see any errors. I am very much novice to sharepoint so can't add much on this post.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you didn't receive any errors! But you cannot loop over the SPListItemCollection (collListItems) and keep deleting its item simultaneously. You see, foreach loop internally calls the [GetEnumerator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable.getenumerator%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which strictly requires that the collection remain enact i.e., one cannot change the collection while iterating. What you can do here is to replace the foreach with a for loop:

```
for (int i = collListItems.Count-1; i>= 0; i--)
{
    collListItems[i].File.UndoCheckOut();
    collListItems[i].File.CheckOut();
    collListItems[i].Delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
{
    //file.UndoCheckOut();
    //file.CheckOut();
    oListItem.File.UndoCheckOut();
    oListItem.File.CheckOut();

    SPListItem itemToDelete = list.GetItemById(oListItem.Id);
    itemToDelete.Delete();
}
```

Comment: There's one big drawback in your approach. You first initialize the `collListItems` with all the ListItems of a List. You again query to get the same ListItem again one by one from SP using the `GetItemById()`. So each ListItem is queried twice before actually getting deleting and the time for the entire process will also keep increasing exponentially.